# Ordering data frame based on specific row order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am ordering a data frame that is much larger than the below example, and I am working to find an automated solution to order them correctly based on a specified row order that includes various subtotal rows placed throughout the data frame. How would I order this data frame automatically so that it sorts those subtotal rows in the correct places?

Original df without the right order:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Comp':['Active','Active','Active','Active','BRAKE','Active','Active','Active','BRAKE','Active','Active','Active','Active'],\
                     'Source':['Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-MM','BRAKE-IRP','Env-MM','Env-IRP','Env-MM','BRAKE-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-MM','Env-MM'],\
                        'ActCat':['Inv','Inv','RA','Inv','Inv','RA','','','','Inv','RA','Inv','RA'],\
                          'Act':['foo','eggs','buzz','buzz','foo','eggs','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal'],\
                          'OG20':[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,10,5,3,3,4,6],\
                          'OG21':[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,10,5,3,3,4,6],'OG22':[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,10,5,3,3,4,6]})
```

[image]

What I have tried:

```
df['sort_helper'] = df['Act'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == "Subtotal" else 0)

df.sort_values(by=['Comp','Source','ActCat','sort_helper','Act'], inplace=True)
```

Desired Output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Comp':['Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','Active','BRAKE','BRAKE','BRAKE','BRAKE'],\
                     'Source':['Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-IRP','Env-MM','Env-MM','Env-MM','Env-MM','Env-MM','','BRAKE-IRP','BRAKE-IRP','BRAKE-IRP',''],\
                        'ActCat':['Inv','Inv','Inv','RA','RA','','Inv','Inv','RA','RA','','','Inv','Inv','',''],\
                          'Act':['foo','eggs','Subtotal','buzz','Subtotal','Subtotal','buzz','Subtotal','eggs','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal','foo','Subtotal','Subtotal','Subtotal'],\
                          'OG20':[1,2,3,3,3,6,4,4,6,6,10,16,6,6,6,6],\
                          'OG21':[1,2,3,3,3,6,4,4,6,6,10,16,6,6,6,6],'OG22':[1,2,3,3,3,6,4,4,6,6,10,16,6,6,6,6]})
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: @MichaelButscher It puts the subtotal rows in the wrong order. I am trying to get any corresponding row that has "Subtotal" value in the 'Act' column to be after the rows it subtotals.

Comment: Please double check the order in your output, this doesn't match the logic of sorting by Act as last key

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I've tried. The longer one yields a result closer to your's. The shorter one might still be adequate.

```
df_sorted = (
    df.groupby(['Comp', 'Source', 'ActCat'], as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda group: group.sort_values(['Act'], ascending=False))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

[image]

Second method: Here, `Act` is sorted as required, but the overall ordering isn't identical to your's.

```
df.sort_values(['Comp', 'Source', 'ActCat', 'Act'], ascending=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your empty strings by NaNs and sort them last (using the default `na_position='last'` of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)):

```
out = (df
   .assign(sort_helper=lambda d: d['Act'].eq('Subtotal'))
   .replace('', float('nan'))
   .sort_values(by=['Comp','Source','ActCat','sort_helper','Act'],
                na_position='last')
 )
```

Output:

```
      Comp     Source ActCat       Act  OG20  OG21  OG22  sort_helper
1   Active    Env-IRP    Inv      eggs     2     2     2        False
0   Active    Env-IRP    Inv       foo     1     1     1        False
9   Active    Env-IRP    Inv  Subtotal     3     3     3         True
2   Active    Env-IRP     RA      buzz     3     3     3        False
10  Active    Env-IRP     RA  Subtotal     3     3     3         True
6   Active    Env-IRP    NaN  Subtotal     6     6     6         True
3   Active     Env-MM    Inv      buzz     4     4     4        False
11  Active     Env-MM    Inv  Subtotal     4     4     4         True
5   Active     Env-MM     RA      eggs     6     6     6        False
12  Active     Env-MM     RA  Subtotal     6     6     6         True
7   Active     Env-MM    NaN  Subtotal    10    10    10         True
4    BRAKE  BRAKE-IRP    Inv       foo     5     5     5        False
8    BRAKE  BRAKE-IRP    NaN  Subtotal     5     5     5         True
```

If you want to keep the original data unchanged, just use the index of the output to reorder:

```
df.loc[out.index]
```

Output:

```
      Comp     Source ActCat       Act  OG20  OG21  OG22
1   Active    Env-IRP    Inv      eggs     2     2     2
0   Active    Env-IRP    Inv       foo     1     1     1
9   Active    Env-IRP    Inv  Subtotal     3     3     3
2   Active    Env-IRP     RA      buzz     3     3     3
10  Active    Env-IRP     RA  Subtotal     3     3     3
6   Active    Env-IRP         Subtotal     6     6     6
3   Active     Env-MM    Inv      buzz     4     4     4
11  Active     Env-MM    Inv  Subtotal     4     4     4
5   Active     Env-MM     RA      eggs     6     6     6
12  Active     Env-MM     RA  Subtotal     6     6     6
7   Active     Env-MM         Subtotal    10    10    10
4    BRAKE  BRAKE-IRP    Inv       foo     5     5     5
8    BRAKE  BRAKE-IRP         Subtotal     5     5     5
```